# Error propagation in normalized data to be used for non-linear modeling

Tags: nonlinear-regression, error-propagation, dose-response

I have been given data where the raw readings conventionally have the mean of "blanks" subtracted from every reading. Then the blank-subtracted readings are divided by the mean blank-subtracted reading for the "zero" treatment. This would be followed by nonlinear modeling (four-parameter log-logistic) of normalized readings vs. treatment amounts. The PI says he wants me to "propagate errors" from the blanks and mean values used to normalize the readings. How would I do this?

Comment: It sounds like you do quite a bit of pre-processing of this data to subtract what might be instrument error, or thresholds for control signals. Then, you fit a curve to the data. After all that, you want to know what the expected values would be as read from the machine in a raw format (with errors propagated). It sounds like the pre-processing is a misstep. Do you trust your non-linear model to model the expected response according to the model?

Comment: This is one possible interpretation of what's meant by "propagating errors" - in any case, it seems totally unrelated to the model-fitting strategy called "backpropagation".

Comment: A lot has happened here, making the situation complex.  If there is no very strong reason to divide by the mean adjusted reading, avoid doing so, because it induces potentially strong correlations among *all* the readings, potentially jeopardizing much of your analysis.  Subtracting the blanks creates a similar problem, but it usually is less severe because it's simpler to analyze the mutual correlations and, if there are enough blanks and their measurement errors aren't too great, the error in their mean can be neglected. It would be good to know more details of the data.

Comment: I trust the modeling, the PI doesn't. I was informed that all that pre-processing is how "the field" usually reports this sort of treatment assay. Cell cultures are treated with different doses of a drug. Culture viability is then measured with a metabolic indicator. From this, a dose-response is to be calculated, primarily an ED50. I already did it with the raw data and mixed-level nonlinear modeling, no pre-processing, but I was then informed that "the field" didn't do modeling on "raw" data. Instead, it did all that preprocessing.